# Firefox extension to bind a site to a tab

Tags: firefox

I’d like to be able to associate a tab with a site in the sense that:

1. When a site’s page is opened in a new tab, the associated tab is reused instead.
2. When an associated tab tries to open an URL that does not belong to the site, a new tab is opened instead.

The main use is to keep often used sites in a pinned tab and keeping them up to date with current work context.

(A Chrome extension that does a similar task is [Reuse Tab](https://github.com/rjregenold/reusetab-chrome).)

Comment: [Published prototype](https://github.com/basilevs/reusetab-firefox/)